# Good pattern to make items catalog with dynamic properties and project file

Tags: c#

I'm looking for some good pattern to complete my app but stuck with linking catalog data to the actual device and its dynamic properties.

Shortly about the app :

1. Application has a local (REST in long future) "catalog" of devices. Contains device definitions, initial property values, photos, graph data and so on;
2. Each device has its type, category and properties, some (not all) of properties has an acceptable range of values (int ranges, filtered enum, or even list of subitems (accessories for example, and accessory properties may also be based on device properties :))
3. User can change some properties, these properties must have field validation (validation may be based on values of other properties)
4. Property availability or/and its value range may be based on the value of another property of this device (in the future may be based even on another device properties). For example, if A = "1" then B can be 2 or 5 only. Or if A = "2" and B = enum.value3 then C is not available to the user at all and so on.
5. User can save/load all selected devices in "project" but without pictures, graph data, and other static properties of the device.
6. Property display names, its values (for example if its value based on enum) and value types (like cm, meters, Celsius...) can be localized.

For now, I've made base project class (serializable) with `IEnumerable<ProjectItemBase>` as host for all added by user devices and `ProjectItemProperty<T>` to store properties of the device.

But I'm stuck with :

- A good way to work with "catalog" data and how to link it to actual device class and its parameters? DB contains a huge amount of data (like pictures and graph data) which we do not need most of the time (as well as we do not need to store them in the project file as they are static for devices), but in preview/printing of device, this data should be displayed. But property localized data and other things we need all the time.
- Make device properties most flexible (but also not too complex), with validation and dependency on other properties with value filter?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a FILE as a database when you have very large amount of data.  Reading a parsing a file is not as efficient as using a database that is designed to handle large amounts of data.  Also using a file will give access issues if multiple users are using the same file. I would recommend using SQL Server (or Express).  You can download Express for free from MSDN and will solve all your issues.

Comment: Im using SQLite, so its one file, and its ok for single user access as only one instance of app can be launched at same time :) I cant use actual database service as app must be non-dependent on any external service. Also its easier to update one file than db :)

Comment: SQL Server is a real database server that is designed for multi-user environment and has locking mechanism to prevent conflicts when more than on user access same data.  SQL Server is also multi-threaded which will user multiple cores in the microprocessor.  SQLite is not a server and is file bases and must open and read file every time it is used.  SQLite is also not designed for multi-user.  SQL Server in most cases will run quicker than SQLite.

Comment: I know :) But moving to full sql will not help in my question :)

Comment: Why not? Are you using Entity?  With SQLite you have to read the entire file every time you open the connection which takes time even though you do not NEED the data. SQL Server once start only reads the data that is part of the query.One of you question is about "data you do not need" and I keep on saying SQL Serer will run faster especially when you do not need all the data.Your real question is really how to increase speed and reduce the memory used by the database.SQLite you have to read the entire file into memory while SQL Server has links into the file so the entire db is not in memory.

Comment: Because app should not be dependent on any external service. Including SQL.

Comment: Is there a requirement app should not be dependent on other applications?  You can just look at one requirement to determine the BEST SOLUTION.  You have to look at entire project requirements to determine answer to questions like this.  You can still use Entity with SQLite or SQL Server to link classes to database provided you designed the classes to be consistent with the database architecture.  With Entity you can access the database with linq and use <T> definitions to give flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, i know how SQL works, i have SQL cluster, i have a lot of web-apps working with SQL servers, using Entity, using Dapper and pure T-SQL. But this app should use this one single db file with sqlite, thats not part of a question :)

Comment: I answered question in last posting saying either SQL Server or SQLite.

Comment: My System Engineering teacher said : "Requirements come from two places 1) Written Requirements 2) Peoples Visions.  It is the job of a System Engineer to take peoples visions and turn them into written requirement".  You have a vision : "DB contains a huge amount of data that we do not want to read all the time".  The real requirements is Execution Time and Memory Usage.  With SQLite you want Vapor Ware, if you expect to read only a portion of the database.  I'm trying to solve your real requirements and not a vision.

Comment: Ok, i've moved whole project to MS SQL cluster, moved logs to SSD NAS, 8 latest xeons do the job, now i can calculate whole universe and save it, index it, build fastest reports in the world ... But how the hell it answers my question? :) I have not asked about sql vs sqlite, right? :)

Comment: Well if you asked a real questions instead of a vision, you would have a real answer.

Comment: Real question of programming pattern for dynamic properties and their dependency on data in database not seems to be sql or performance-related :) And yep, english is not my first language, but im trying :))

Answer (score 0):

I've made a base class to store property data

```
[Serializable]
public class Property<T>: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected T _Value;

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return Value;
        }
        set
        {
            _Value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface
    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

So, for now, I can inherit it like

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeProperty : Property<int>
{...}
```

Inherited property class can contain reference item ID in the database and can contain additional fields like property localized name, availability and validation. Also by using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, I will be able to inform other properties and/or items host on value changes.

Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Isn't `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented for classes that contain properties, not the properties themselves?